# Depth First Search algorithm with target node

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have to use DFS algorithm for my university project. I saw this link [DFS](https://www.javatpoint.com/depth-first-search-algorithm) but i face this problem. The Depth First Search algorithm is Traversal it goes to every node in the graph but i want to define a target node when i reach to it i want to stop the algorithm
i tried the following code but it still go to all node

```
void DFSUtil(int v, int goal, boolean visited[]) {
            visited[v] = true;

            Iterator<Integer> i = adj[v].listIterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                int n = i.next();
                if (!visited[n]) {
                    if (n == goal) {
                        System.err.print(infoLinkedList.get(1).nameStation+":");
                        System.err.print(" |"+goal+ "| -> ");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: In DFS, we need to visit all children of a node. This, in essence, means we need two loops: one for the termination condition, one to iterate over all children of the current node. Normally, we do this by adding a `Dequeue<...>` of work to do. If we read and write from the same side, we have a DFS algorithm. If we read form one side, but write to anoteher, we have BFS. I have a DFS implementation [here](https://github.com/turing85/advent-of-code-2022/blob/main/day-19/src/main/java/de/turing85/advent/of/code/tttt/day/nineteen/model/BlueprintEvaluator.java#L33) if you want to take a look.

Comment: Also, if the target node is a final node of the graph or even absent at all, then all nodes will be traversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is not DFS, it visits the neighbours of the node `v` and that's it. A DFS would look something like this:

```java
void DFSUtil(int v, int goal, boolean visited[]) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.add(v);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            var n = stack.pop();
            if (!visited[n]) {
                if (n == goal) {
                    System.err.print(infoLinkedList.get(1).nameStation + ":");
                    System.err.print(" |" + goal + "| -> ");
                    return;
                }
                visited[n] = true;
                Iterator<Integer> i = adj[n].listIterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    stack.add(i.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```